# Why do I keep getting and unused arguments error?

Tags: r, knn

I am applying the kNN algorithm to a data set with 6 predictors and 1 class variable with 1599 rows, I have reviewed my syntax many times and gone back over other examples to try and find my error. I am totally bamboozled at present. I have broken the data set up into test_set, test_set_class, training_set, training_set_class. Any assistance would be fantastic, see below for the code and error.

```
num_obs <- nrow(wine_preds3)
# set the sample size to be 80%
sample_size <- as.integer(num_obs*0.8)
# set the seed for the sample split
set.seed(0)
# randomly split 80% the data indexes in reduced wine
split_index <- sample(num_obs, size = sample_size, replace = FALSE)
# subset the reduced wine into a testing subset of 20%
test_wine_preds <- wine_preds3[-split_index, 1:6]
test_wine_class <- wine_preds3[-split_index, 7]
# subset the reduced wine into a training subset of 80%
train_wine_preds <- wine_preds3[split_index, 1:6]
train_wine_class <- wine_preds3[split_index, 7]
Pred_class <- kNN(train = train_wine_preds, test = test_wine_preds, cl = train_wine_class, k = 15)

Error in kNN(train = train_wine_preds, test = test_wine_preds, cl = train_wine_class,  : 
  unused arguments (train = train_wine_preds, test = test_wine_preds, cl = train_wine_class)
```

Comment: What kind of knn package you used?

Comment: I think you're using the wrong function. Your command looks like you should be using `knn` from the **class** package.

Comment: If I'm correct, you're using `kNN` and mistaking it for `knn` (lower case). The formals are `class::knn(train, test, cl, k = 1, l = 0, prob = FALSE, use.all = TRUE)` and `dbscan::kNN(x, k, query = NULL, sort = TRUE, search = "kdtree", bucketSize = 10, splitRule = "suggest", approx = 0)` (very different argument list).

Comment: Thank you everyone, something so simple. Always seems to work that way with me.

Comment: @r2evans You should make that an answer below!